# Как убрать ненужную метку из поиска search.php woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' );?>" class="search-form">
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" class = "input1" placeholder = "..." />
  <?php if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) : ?>
  
    <?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['product_tag']) && !empty($_REQUEST['product_tag'])) {
      $optsetlect=$_REQUEST['product_tag'];
    } else {
      $optsetlect=0;
    }               
    $args = array(
      'show_option_all' => esc_html__( 'Все категории', 'woocommerce' ),
      'hierarchical' => 1,
      'depth' => 2,
      'class' => 'cat',
      'echo' => 1,
      'value_field' => 'slug',
      'selected' => $optsetlect
    );
    $args['taxonomy'] = 'product_tag';
    $args['name'] = 'product_tag';
    $args['class'] = 'cate-dropdown hidden-xs';
    
    wp_dropdown_categories($args);
    ?>

    <input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type">
  
  <?php endif; ?>

  <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value = "product">
  <input type="hidden" name="sp" value="1">
</form>
```

подскажите пжл как удалить не нужную категорию с выпадающего меню поиска?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалить таксономию `(product_tag)` из массива `$args`, который используется для вызова `wp_dropdown_categories`. Например, если нужно удалить катег. "Unwanted", нужно добавить перед `wp_dropdown_categories`:

```
$unwanted_term = get_term_by('name', 'Unwanted', 'product_tag');
$args['exclude'] = $unwanted_term->term_id;
```

Это исключит термин "Unwanted" из меню выпадающего списка. А если вам нужно удалить несколько катег., используй массив:

```
$args['exclude'] = array( $unwanted_term1->term_id, $unwanted_term2->term_id );
```

Если не помогло, используй фильтр `woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args`, вот это нужно добавить в `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'exclude_product_categories_widget' );
function exclude_product_categories_widget( $list_args ) {
    $list_args['exclude'] = 'Unwanted'; // ID or Slug of unwanted term
    return $list_args;
}
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо ! Все сработало!